# Why are my screen colors slightly more saturated on X11 than Wayland?

Tags: xorg, wayland, colors, macbook-air, color-depth

I'm running Ubuntu 22.04.1 on my 2012 MacBook Air 11 inch with a Core i7-3667U (with Intel integrated graphics). I use a custom ICC color profile when running Linux because the default colors are very blue, especially compared to what I get on MacOS. However, for whatever reason, my colors appear slightly more saturated on X11 than Wayland. Curiously, whenever I log out of X11 without rebooting and log in to Wayland, the colors remain more saturated, and using the Colors section in GNOME's settings doesn't actually have any effect. To be clear, both X11 and Wayland are using the exact same ICC profile selected through GNOME's settings.

Because I prefer the appearance of X11's colors, I'd like to find a way to either a. Retain X11's colors on Wayland even after reboot, or b. manually increase the saturation on Wayland to be on par with X11 and MacOS. Are either of these things possible?

Also, here is a (slightly unscientific) image reference for the difference in colors.
[Top is X11; bottom is Wayland](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1w1hR.jpg)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Search settings in your apps.

Go find a section called Color.

Click on the one for your screen so you'll get something like this.

[image]

Press add profile

And search for sRGB

Comment: Hi there, please provide some context as to what this does and why you think it would be helpful. That way people can decide for themselves if they think it would help them.

Comment: This doesn't help. I only have one option in Xorg - Automatic